# Поиск значений массива в массиве

Tags: массивы, php

Имеем массив

```
$a =  array("qwe","asd","zxc");
```

И массив

```
$b = array("zxc","qwe");
```

Нужно определить, имеются ли значения из массива `$b` в массиве `$a`.

Что-то тупняк навалился, не пойму, как сделать.

Comment: @nikoyar, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(bool) array_intersect($a, $b);
```

Comment: ну, конечно! спасибо :)

Answer (score 2):

1. http://www.php.su/functions/?array-diff
2. http://www.php.su/functions/?array-intersect